# return index value from index image in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, pixel

I would like to extract index value from indexed image from specific coordinate `(X, Y)` in Matlab.

I have used `impixel` which is working perfectly for an image, however, when I use it in a loop it returns NaN or incorrect values.

```
 filename  = 'realworldCoordinates.txt';  % define the file name 
delimiterIn = '';  % set parameter for seperating values 
headerlinesIn = 1;   %which line is header

[A] = importdata (filename);

I = A.data (:,:);
X1 = II(:,1);  %define X1
Y1 = II(:,2);  % define Y1

X2 = II(:,3);  %define X2
Y2 = II(:,4);  %define Y2

for k = 1: numel (Imfiles(1:2))
    fileNames = Imfiles(k).name;
    imIndexed = imread (fileNames);
    Z1 = impixel (imIndexed(:,:,3), X1,Y1);
    Z2 = impixel (imIndexed(:,:,3), X2,Y2);         
    end
```

Comment: Why don't you directly access the pixel using `imIndexed(X1,Y1,3)`?

Comment: Because I want to read X and Y from a table and I need each row in the table being used for one image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a @mike Thomson suggestion,  I just fixed my code as below:

```
    filename  = 'realworldCoordinates.txt';  % define the file name 
    delimiterIn = '';  % set parameter for seperating values 
    headerlinesIn = 1;   %which line is header

    [A] = importdata (filename);

    I = A.data (:,:);
    X1 = II(:,1);  %define X1
    Y1 = II(:,2);  % define Y1

    X2 = II(:,3);  %define X2
    Y2 = II(:,4);  %define Y2

 %loop for reading data from txt file and return the index value 

       for k = 1: numel (Imfiles(1:2))
            fileNames = Imfiles(k).name;
            imIndexed = imread (fileNames);
            Z1 = impixel (imIndexed(:,:,3), X1(k),Y1(k));
            Z1(k,:) =(Z1(:,:,1))         
            Z2 = impixel (imIndexed(:,:,3), X2(k),Y2(k)); 
            Z2(k,:) =(Z2(:,:,1))         
        end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have your full code, I can only assume a few things about what is going on and can't actually try this solution to see if it does what you want. First, I'm not sure impixel is supposed to support being passed only the 3rd element of each pixel that you're doing with `imIndexed(:,:,3)`, but rather that you should get the 3rd element after using impixel. Try doing something like this instead:

```
for k = 1: numel (Imfiles(1:2))
    fileNames = Imfiles(k).name;
    imIndexed = imread (fileNames);
    tmp1 = impixel (imIndexed, X1,Y1);
    tmp2 = impixel (imIndexed, X2,Y2);
    Z1 = tmp1(3);
    Z2 = tmp2(3);
end
```